# Deleting anything in webapps directory doesn't work using Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: debian, permissions, tomcat

I ran into an issue where `rm` doesn't delete anything from the `webapps` directory using Apache Tomcat 7, but `rm` does work in any other directory.

The Tomcat service is down. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you try but fail? Permission errors? Who owns the folder and what user are you running `rm` as?

Comment: Yeah I get permission error rm: cannot remove ‘8888.war’: Permission denied. Folder belongs to root and I'm running rm as root too.

Comment: **Show us what you did.** It does not sound like tomcat has anything to do with it, unless it is a container. Show details: show what you did, and what happened.

Answer (score -1):

Your Tomcat instance has been attacked. 
Check if Tomcat manager is exposed and is NOT secured. 
Secure it immediately. 
Change the passwords in `conf/tomcat-users.xml`.

You are unable to delete the malicious war `8888.war` from the `webapps` directory
because this war has run commands
that change the attributes of the `webapps` directory – made it write-protected.

To check and revert you need to use the following instructions
(from [How can I delete a write-<s>only</s>-protected folder?](https://askubuntu.com/a/770640/325633) (on Ask Ubuntu)):

> Use the `lsattr` command to verify that the file/folder is not write protected using the extended `i` attribute – output should be:
>
> ```
> ----i-------- /my/locked/directory
> ```
>
> To remove the `i` attribute you can run:
>
> ```
> sudo chattr -i /my/locked/directory
> ```
>
> then check again with `lsattr`. 
> The `i` should have been removed. 
> If it was removed, run the `sudo rm -r` command
> using the instructions *[in the linked answer]*.

<sup>[Minimally edited for style.]</sup>

To read about what malicious work this attack could do,
refer to [What the Chinese deploy into your Tomcat server
if you don't secure it](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8226942) on "Hacker News" (ycombinator.com),
and stay protected.